# I want to convert this javascript code to Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var footerArray = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i<footerArray.length; i++)
{
  footerArray[i].addEventListener("click",function(e)
    {
      console.log(e.target.innerHTML)
    }, false);
}
```

this is the code that i have the works to console log the elements in the footer. I need to convert it to jquery and have no idea how.

Comment: did you try anything... if so what is the problem you are facing

Comment: Start by reading the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/, http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/. I'm serious. Those articles (not only the ones I linked to) contain the information to get you started with jQuery, and probably learn much more than if someone just posts some code here.

Comment: If it works, why convert it to use jQuery? For what you have here it doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: i have tried looking and cant find anything that helps..im probably searching in the wrong places. I finally started to understand javascript and jquery is a different monster..i just dont know where to start

Comment: start from http://learn.jquery.com/ - there is sufficient information there to start working with jQuery

Comment: thanks this looks easy enough to understand

Comment: also your script may not always give desired result if the anchor element contains another element like `<a href="#">something 2<span>span</span></a>`

Comment: jQuery ***IS*** JavaScript

Comment: in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z4CeH/1/) click `span` to see the difference

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the conversion of some very specific code and it won't be very useful for anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the quickest way:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var footerArray = $('a'); 

$.each(footerArray, function() {
     $(this).on('click',function()  {
        console.log($(this).html());
    });
});
```

or basically:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
     console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items = $('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        var it = $(items[i]);
        it.click(function() {
            console.log($(this).html());
        });
    }
});
    </script>
    <style>
.highlight {
    color: red;
}   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript: return false">Link 1</a>
    <a href="javascript: return false">Link 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note that you should avoid attaching event handlers like this. In most cases, there is no need to iterate over the jQuery object manually.